# Numeric control percentage type to show 5% instead of 0.05 on focus

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

is there any configuration in the control to show 5% on focus too instead of 0.05,
for percentage its right to show 0.05 as value and on focus out it displays 5% but if there is a configurable switch to do the show 5% both times other than writing custom focus and blur events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in number formatting allows to escape the '%' symbol, thus skipping the default `value * 100` behavior.

Here is how you can do this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-numerictextbox
        [value]="value"
        [format]="format"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  public value: number = 5;
  public format: string = "#.# \\%";

  constructor(public intl: IntlService) {}
}
```

Runnable demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba05nP4LCgjuKjssSJzE?p=preview

More details about the formats can be found in the `kendo-intl` repo:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/master/docs/num-formatting/index.md#custom